# Can't replace placeholder of PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext, placeholder

So I have this function which replaces a specific placerholder of my template pdf file and saves the replaced data as a new file:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfDictionary dict = reader.getPageN(1);
    PdfObject object = dict.getDirectObject(PdfName.CONTENTS);
    if (object instanceof PRStream) {
        PRStream stream = (PRStream) object;
        byte[] data = PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream);
        stream.setData(new String(data).replace("{0}", "one for all").getBytes());

    }
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();

    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        File myFile = new File(dest);
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);

    }
}
```

This is how my src (template file) looks like:

[image: templateFile]

After I create the new file, it looks the same. The placeholder did not change. How can I replace a text using iText

Comment: The content replacement code you have works only for extremely simple pdfs. In general the codes representing "{0}" neither need to be connected (each character may be drawn in a separate instruction) nor need to be ascii encoded (the encoding may be completely arbitrary), and the font used for them may be a subset font resulting in your replacement being not renderable.